# Why does Haskell forbid functions with "different numbers of arguments"

Tags: haskell, types

I was playing around in Haskell and I wrote the following code

```hs
d::Integer->Integer
d 4=7
d=(*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8XKyjOvJDU9tUjXDsrgSlEwsTXnSrHV0DLS/J@bmJlnW1CUmVeikptYoJASbainZ2wQ@x8A)

In my mind this should return 7 when the input is 4 and twice the input otherwise.  However a bit to my surprise this doesn't even compile, it gives the error in GHC:

```hs
Equations for ‘d’ have different numbers of arguments
```

Now in some ways the compiler is correct, the two definitions of `d` do have different numbers of arguments, however they do both take one argument (The first requires it be both `Eq` and `Num`, while the second only requires `Num`) and produce a member of the `Num` type class.

```hs
 ⚙ > ~/projects > ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> f 4=7
Prelude> :t f
f :: (Eq a, Num a, Num p) => a -> p
Prelude> g=(*2)
Prelude> :t g
g :: Num a => a -> a
Prelude>
```

In principle I see no reason why the compiler shouldn't allow this.

Why does the compiler give an error here?  What is the benefit/design philosophy of doing so?

---

This is not a debugging question, I know the issue and I know how to fix it, here is a working version of the code as proof.

```hs
d::Integer->Integer
d 4=7
d x=x*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8XKyjOvJDU9tUjXDsrgSlEwsTUHkhW2FVpG/3MTM/NsC4oy80pUchMLFFKiDfX0jA1i/wMA)

Comment: This is **not** ghc specific, it is a restriction that Haskell has.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good to know, I wasn't able to check any other compilers, I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Also, note that it says the *equations* have different number of arguments not the "*functions*".